# Does the WP_Query 'private' argument for post status only apply to privately published content?

Tags: wp-query, post-status

The only peice of code that I can find that applies to this is on line 2430 in query.php in WP 3.4.1

```
foreach ( get_post_stati() as $status ) {
  if ( in_array( $status, $q_status ) ) {
    if ( 'private' == $status )
      $p_status[] = "$wpdb->posts.post_status = '$status'";
    else
      $r_status[] = "$wpdb->posts.post_status = '$status'";
  }
}
```

From what I've experienced, with any other `post_status` param added with the '`private`' param added, the results will not be cross compared. For example, both (public) '`publish`' and '`private`' added, it will still return both publicly published posts and privately published posts. Here is a simple piece of code demonstrating it.

```
function example($post_status       = array('publish'),
                 $excludeCurrent    = 0)
{
    $post_type_names = get_post_types('', 'names');
    $skip_post_types = array('attachment', 'revision', 'nav_menu_item');
    foreach ($skip_post_types as $value)
    {
        unset($post_type_names[$value]);
    }
    unset($value);
    unset($skip_post_types);

    $arg_query = array(
        'post_type'         => $post_type_names,
        'post_status'       => $post_status,
        'post__not_in'      => $excludeCurrent,
        'nopaging'          => TRUE,
        'order'             => 'date',
        'orderby'           => 'DESC',
        'suppress_filters'  => TRUE
    );

    $example_query = new WP_Query($arg_query);
    return $example_query;
}

$example01 = example(); //returns only publicly published posts.
$example02 = example(array('publish', 'private')); //returns both publicly and privatly published posts.
$example03 = example(array('future', 'private')); //returns both publicly and privatly future posts as well as privatly published posts.
```

The third example is where my biggest issue is. After digging more before I posted this. I noticed that the operator '`OR`' is always added between both post_status for the MySQL query. I also notice that the **search** param may offer a solution. So is there some additional filter that I may be missing? Possibly one to switch the MySQL operator '`OR`' to '`AND`'?